# Navigator in React Native between components

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation

I want to make a simple navigation to another compnente. I tried it with the createStackNavigator but unfortunately it did not work. The first page is App and the second page is AppLoggedin. It is my first React Native App. Then I would like to navigate to info and impressum later. Can you help me please?

https://snack.expo.io/@knefie/outsource-neu

Comment: please put the most important code parts in question description using ```code```,
it will help people to quicker spot your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation'
     import App from './App'
     import AppLoggedIn from './AppLoggedIn'

     const Stack = createStackNavigator(
     {
      App: {
          screen: App
      },
      AppLoggedIn:{
          screen:AppLoggedin

      },
      );

      export default Stack;
```

In your App.js put this :

```
      import Stack from './stacknavigator'
      export default class App extends Component {
      render(
            <Stack>

         )
         }
```

For navigate between screens:

```
       this.props.navigation.navigate('App')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  loginFlow: createStackNavigator({
    Signup: SignupScreen,
    Signin: SigninScreen
  }),
  mainFlow: createStackNavigator({
      Home: HomeScreen,
      Settings: SettingsScreen
    }),
  });
 export default createAppContainer(switchNavigator);
```

Try something like this.
Make sure that you import all you need like AppContainer and Navigators.

When you have this setup due navigtion you can navigate between screens with the onPress property from the Button:

in your function use such like:

```
<Button 
onPress={() => navigation.navigate('//The name of the screen where you want to navigate to. )>
</Button>
```

At last give your function the navigation props;
const NameOfYourScreen = (props) => {
...
}